# Firebase - Future::ErrorMessage()

Tags: c++, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm currently working with the C++ Firebase-authentication API and struggling to find any documentation on errors.

There's three authentication error codes;
`kAuthErrorNone`, `kAuthErrorUnimplemented` & `kAuthErrorFailure`

I'm using `Future::ErrorMessage()` to pull out a more concise error description in the fail cases which I'm then (rather disgustingly) mapping to an internal (more concise) error code in my handler. There isn't however any documentation (that I can find) describing the detailed error messages covered by `ErrorMessage()`.

So I feel I must be missing a trick - how are people doing useful error handling with the C++ Auth API?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

first you should check status of Future class, if status is kFutureCompleted then check Error for kAuthErrorNone or something.

Comment: Thanks for your response Dcow. So I'm first checking the future for completion and then checking the auth error response. In the event where its kAuthErrorFailure I'm then pulling out the error string.


The problem is that the specifics of the error are in a string. There's no corresponding enumerated type to key these and there's no documentation covering all the possible error strings. So there's no sensible way that I can see to deal with all the error outcomes.